# POSTing XML content to curl through a variable

Tags: xml, bash, shell

I am trying to do a curl post command in my shell script. 
I want to POST an xml , which is in a variable `$xml_content` .

I tried using below commands:

```
 curl --request POST   --url "$URL"   --header 'cache-control: no-cache'   --header 'content-type: application/xml' --data  ${xml_content}


echo ${xml_content} | xmllint format -| curl --request POST   --url "$URL"   --header 'cache-control: no-cache'   --header 'content-type: application/xml' --data @-
```

Both of them shows below response :

```
Request is an invalid format Invalid Request
```

But when I use:

```
curl --request POST   --url "$URL"   --header 'cache-control: no-cache'   --header 'content-type: application/xml' --data  "the content to be posted ie the xml content itself without using variable name"
```

it works.

Question : How should a variable be passed into a curl post . Am i using correct syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is not `curl`, but the way shell passes the arguments to `curl`.

As `xml_content` might contain characters that have special significance to shell, you need to put it in double quotes while passing to `curl`:

```
curl --request POST --url "$URL" --header 'cache-control: no-cache' --header 'content-type: application/xml' --data "$xml_content"
```

Take a look at this post on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange which talks about the topic of quoting:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary

Comment: you are right . Adding quotes fixed the issue . Thanks